Referencing secret_env values in docker run args in Cloudbuild template in Terraform
I need to reference a secretEnv value from secrets manager in my docker run arg in a CloudBuild step, but I've tried many variation of $DATABASE_CREDENTIALS and I haven't had any success. The secret availability permissions are configured properly but I'm can't get the env var to exist or have the appropriate value. Below is what my code looks like
step {
  id       = "foobar"
  name     = "docker"
  secret_env = ["DATABASE_CREDENTIALS",]
  wait_for = ["setup-proxy", "build-foobar"]
  entrypoint = "sh"
  args     = ["-c", "/workspace/cloud_sql_proxy -dir=/workspace -instances='${var.cloud_sql_connection_name}' & sleep 3 &&  docker run -v /workspace:/root --env DATABASE_CREDENTIALS='$$DATABASE_CREDENTIALS' '$FOOBAR_IMG'"]
}

available_secrets {
  secret_manager {
    version_name = "${google_secret_manager_secret.postgres_creds.name}/versions/latest"
    env = "DATABASE_CREDENTIALS"
  }
}

Is it possible to reference secret_env values in cloudbuild args?

I finally got it to work using double quotes \"\". Extremely frustrating experience.
  args     = ["-c", "/workspace/cloud_sql_proxy -dir=/workspace -instances='${var.cloud_sql_connection_name}' & sleep 3 &&  docker run -v /workspace:/root --env DATABASE_CREDENTIALS=\"$$DATABASE_CREDENTIALS\" '$FOOBAR_IMG'"]

